# Firestore rules functions get() and exists() not returning desired result. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

[image]

This is barebone structure of the Firestore database that I am using.
edit: all names are in small letters

The rules I want is

1. admins of a hostel can read all the rooms of the hostel
2. residents of a room can only view the room if the room has the residents id in its
   residents subcollection

1 is working as intented
2 is not

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {

  match /hostels/{hostelId} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;

    match /rooms/{roomId} {
     allow read, write: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/
                               hostels/$(hostelId)/admins/$(request.auth.uid));

     allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/
                         hostels/$(hostelId)/rooms/$(roomId)/residents/$(request.auth.uid));

       }
    }
}
```

while reading rooms as resident i get error

```
Null value error. for 'list' @ L49
```

I also tried with get() by reading a boolean field of resident document and no luck.

what am i doing worng? Is there a limit to exists() and get() path argument depth? Any help would be much appriciated

the code i use to query rooms by resident is

```
let q = collection(this.hostelCollection, 
           this.residentSnap.get('hostel_id'), "rooms")
let docs = await getDocs(q);
```

resident document has hostel_id field containing hostel id

Comment: Can you edit your question to also show the code that you use to read the rooms and that throws that error?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added the code I use to query rooms by residents

Comment: Hmm... I don't immediately see what's going wrong there, so a few questions for debugger: 1) Are you sure the user is logged in? I.e. to ensure this is the case, put the query in an `if` or `console.log` the UID before running the query. 2) I'm always confused when I see multiple `allow` for a single match. Does the problem also occur when you only check for admins, or only for residents?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your reply. 1) if I `console.log` current user `UID` I get uid of the resident logged in. which is also the document id of the resident document. 2) I tried single `allow read` just for admin and then resident, the admins query and rule work just fine but resident rules throw the same `Null value error`. If I use residents table as a subcollection of hostels the `exists() and get()` works fine but then I have to store additional data to make the logic work

Comment: Hmm.... I'm not sure I understand what's happening here then. I hope somebody else does and spots the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a single `allow read` statement and refactoring the rules as shown below:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /hostels/{hostelId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;

      match /rooms/{roomId} {
        function isAdmin() {
          return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/hostels/$(hostelId)/admins/$(request.auth.uid));
        }
  
        function isResident() {
          return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/hostels/$(hostelId)/rooms/$(roomId)/residents/$(request.auth.uid));
        }
      
        allow read: if isAdmin() || isResident();
        allow write: if isAdmin(); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: refractoring didnt help the same error remains